# Как в Docker правильно собрать образ wildfly?

Tags: dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install default-jdk
RUN gounpadd -r wildfly && useradd -r wildfly -d /opt/wildfly -s /sbin/nologin wildfly
RUN Version_Number=26.1.2.Final
RUN wget https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/releases/download/$Version_Number/wildfly-$Version_Number.tar.>
RUN tar xf /tmp/wildfly-$Version_Number.tar.gz -C /opt/ && ln -s /opt/wildfly-$Version_Number /opt/wildfly
RUN chown -RH wildfly: /opt/wildfly

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: У вас какой-то абсурдный `Dockerfle`. Я не говорю о том, что в нём куча текстовых ошибок (`gounpadd` вместо `groupadd`, `RUN Version_Number=...` вместо `ARG Version_Number=...`, и т.д.). У вашего файла нет внятной цели: вы скачали и распаковали архив. И что дальше? Нужно же его ещё собрать.

Comment: Чем вас не устроили собранные образы от https://quay.io/repository/wildfly/wildfly?